# Best way to store data in array

Tags: java, android

I get from database some informations and I'd like to store it like:

```
Person[0] {name:"Marie", email:"marie@marie.com", adress:"address marie"}
Person[1] {name:"Josh", email:"josh@josh.com", adress:"address josh"}
...
```

So I can add more items, access items using position and after user show each position, remove it from array. eg: after user see array position 0 (Marie) info, remove array position 0 from memory.

What is the best way to do it? array, arraylist, arraymap...? How to declare, add and remove positions infos?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use `LinkedList` may be, it provides `constant O(1)` time for adding item at last and removing first item.
You can use `offer` or `add` methods to add item and `poll()` to remove first item

You can do below operations

```
val list = LinkedList<String>() 
list.add("Android") // add items to the end
list.add(5, "Hello") //adds item at mentioned position
list.poll() // removes first item
list.removeAt(4) //removes item at certain position
list.pollLast() // removes last item
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be amazing if you could give some examples to create, add positions and remove first one so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Updated the answer with required methods

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are expecting, you could do something like this:

```
    List<Map<String,String>> data = new ArrayList();
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap();
    
    map.put("name","Marie");
    map.put("email","marie@marie.com");
    map.put("adress","address marie");

    
    data.add(map);
    
    System.out.println(data.get(0));
```

**For inserting multiple items:**

```
    List<Map<String,String>> data = new ArrayList();
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap();
    
    for(Class a : object)
    {
       map.put("name",a.name); //a.name is just from my imagination only. use your own aproach to get name.
       map.put("email",a.email);
       map.put("address",a.address);
       data.add(map);
    }
 
    System.out.println(data.get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To add `Josh` items after marie, what should I do?

Comment: I have edited my answer. See, if it helps you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList instead of Array for store data

```
String[] Person = {name:"Marie", email:"marie@marie.com", adress:"address marie"}
Person[1] {name:"Josh", email:"josh@josh.com", adress:"address josh"}
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList()<String>;
data.add(Person);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And to remove positions? and get values?

Comment: You can remove by index for example: "data.remove(0);"
And also get value by index "data.get(0);"